# Representing differences between database representation and object representation in JPA

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I am working with a legacy database that makes frequent use of blobs of JSON stored as text. I am trying to write some JPA classes that will hide this implementation detail, make it easier to work with the database, and allow us to refactor the database schema in the future. My current approach is:

```
class MyTableObject{

     @Lob
     @Column(name = "stuff")
     private String jsonString;

     public List<Stuff> getStuff(){
         return jsonToStuff(jsonString);
     }

     public setStuff(List<Stuff> stuff){
         jsonString = stuffToJsonString(stuff);
     }

}
```

Here, the representation is always as a JSON string in both the the database and the Object and although it works (so far) , it is pretty inefficient as the JSON has to be parsed every time the state of the object is modified. I appreciate that I could improve performance of my current solution by cacheing the Stuff objects in memory, but I would still have to serialize them to JSON every time the setter is called and ensure that the 2 representations of the state (Objects and JSON) were always in sync. What I would like to be able to do is to tell the framework to convert my field on the way in and out, something like:

```
class MyTableObject{


     private List<Stuff> stuff;

     @Lob
     @Column(name = "stuff")
     public String getStuffAsJsonString(){
         return stuffToJsonString(stuff);
     }

     @Column(name = "stuff")
     public setStuffFromJsonString(String jsonString){
         stuff = stuffFromJsonString(jsonString);
     }

}
```

However, as far as I know annotations are only valid on the getter. Can I achieve something like the above - with one representation in the Object and a different representation in the database? I am new to JPA so I could easily be missing something obvious.

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just annotate the getter. The corresponding setter will be used by JPA when the object is  loaded from the database.

I would use a protected property that is only for JPA and a public accessor for the clients.
The public accessor converts the json string to the List of stuffs when it needs it.

In the same way the property accessor methods for JPA converts the list of stuff to the json string if it is needed.

```
class MyTableObject {

     private String jsonStuff;

     private List<Stuff> stuff;

     @Lob
     @Column(name = "stuff")
     protected String getJsonStuff(){
         if(jsonStuff == null){
             jsonStuff = stuffToJsonString(stuff);
         }
         return jsonStuff;
     }

     protected void setJsonStuff(String jsonString){
         if(jsonString != null && jsonString.equals(this.jsonStuff)){
             // the new string is equal to the old one. No need to re-convert.
             return;
         }
         this.jsonStuff = jsonString;
         // jsonStuff changed we have to re-convert json to list
         // thus we set stuff to null
         stuff = null;
     }

     public List<Stuff> getStuff(){
         if(stuff == null){
             stuff = stuffFromJsonString(jsonStuff);
         }
         return Collections.unmodifiableList(stuff);
     }

     public void setStuff(List<String> stuff){
         if(suffListNotChanged(stuff)){
             // the new stuff list is equal to the old one. No need to rebuild json.
             return;
         }
         this.stuff = new ArrayList<String>(stuff);
         // the stuff list changed
         // thus the jsonStuff string must be rebuild
         this.jsonStuff = null;
     }

     private boolean suffListNotChanged(List<Stuff> stuffList){
         ...
     }

     private String stuffToJsonString(List<Stuff> stuffList){
         if(stuffList == null){
             ....
         }
     }

     private List<Stuff> stuffFromJsonString(String stuff){
         if(stuff == null){
             ....
         }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not *exactly* that the annotations are only valid on the getter. A single annotation takes care of the getter and the setter: you don't doubly-annotate.

So, you've basically figured it out already. Remove the extra `@Column(name = "stuff")` on the setter and you're off to the races.

```
class MyTableObject {
     private List<Stuff> stuff;

     @Lob
     @Column(name = "stuff")
     public String getStuffAsJsonString(){
         return stuffToJsonString(stuff);
     }

     public setStuffFromJsonString(String jsonString){
         stuff = stuffFromJsonString(jsonString);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't even to worry for which of the getter/setter should be annotated. The below code should be all set:

```
class MyTableObject{


     @Lob
     @Column(name = "stuff")
     private List<Stuff> stuffAsJsonString;

     public String getStuffAsJsonString(){
         return stuffToJsonString(stuff);
     }

     public setStuffFromJsonString(String jsonString){
         stuff = stuffFromJsonString(jsonString);
     }

}
```